# Matplotlib plot already binned data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the mean local binary patterns histograms of a set of images. Here is what I did:

```
#calculates the lbp
lbp = feature.local_binary_pattern(image, 24, 8, method="uniform")
        
#Now I calculate the histogram of LBP Patterns
(hist, _) = np.histogram(lbp.ravel(), bins=np.arange(0, 27))
```

After that I simply sum up all the LBP histograms and take the mean of them. These are the values found, which are saved in a txt file:

> 2.962000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.476000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.128000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.164000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.282000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.661000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.253000000000000000e+03
>
> 3.378000000000000000e+03
>
> 4.490000000000000000e+03
>
> 5.010000000000000000e+03
>
> 4.337000000000000000e+03
>
> 3.222000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.460000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.495000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.599000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.934000000000000000e+03
>
> 2.526000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.971000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.303000000000000000e+03
>
> 9.900000000000000000e+02
>
> 7.980000000000000000e+02
>
> 8.680000000000000000e+02
>
> 1.119000000000000000e+03
>
> 1.479000000000000000e+03
>
> 4.355000000000000000e+03
>
> 3.112600000000000000e+04

I am trying to simply plot these values (don't need to calculate the histogram, because the values are already from a histogram). Here is what I've tried:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py

#load data
data=np.loadtxt('original_dataset1.txt')
#convert to float
data=data.astype('float32')
#define number of Bins
n_bins = data.max() + 1

plt.style.use("ggplot")
(fig, ax) = plt.subplots()
fig.suptitle("Local Binary Patterns")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("LBP value")
plt.bar(n_bins, data)
fig.savefig('lbp_histogram.png')
```

However, look at the Figure these commands produce:

[image]

I still dont understand what is happening. I would like to make a Figure like the one I produced in Excel using the same data, as follows:[image]

I must confess that I am quite rookie with matplotlib. So, what was my mistake?

Comment: Use bar graph with values you calculated and xtickes as the number of bins in order. It will give you the desired result. Check [link1](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/) and [link2](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/custom_ticker1.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-custom-ticker1-py).

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am quite rookie on this :-(

Comment: instead of n_bins you need actual coordinates of the bars, so smth like np.arange(len(data))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Here the array is your mean values from bins.

```
array = [2962,1476,1128,1164,1282,1661,2253]
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1,)
ax.bar(np.array(range(len(array)))+1,array,color='orangered')
ax.grid(axis='y')
for i, v in enumerate(array):
    ax.text(i+1, v, str(v),color='black',fontweight='bold',
            verticalalignment='bottom',horizontalalignment='center')
plt.savefig('savefig.png',dpi=150)
```

The plot look like this.
[image: Picture]

Comment: It worked. However, the number of bins is messing up the text in the top of them. I will try different font sizes and alignments to try to minimize this issue. Thank you so much.